Lecturer interview presentation in the UK
I was shortlisted for a lecturer post in a research-intensive university in the UK. From the job description, I can see this post is teaching focused. The only research duty seems to be the supervision of students on research projects. For the interview, I was asked to give a 10-minute presentation to present my area of research suitable for a second-year student cohort.
I am quite confused about the "area of research" here. How specific should it be? Should I just pretend I was teaching the students on the broad area? Or should I explain my specific research topic (i.e. the title of the project I am working on) in a way that is accessible for the students?
I would much appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Supervising masters students or doctoral?  Or undergraduate students?

Are you sure it is teaching focussed? If so, the advert would usually say so explicitly, perhaps using a phrase like "teaching track" or "education-focussed". It may just be a badly written advert. A "lecturer" with no further qualification is usually a research-and-teaching position.

It's supervision of both undergraduate and postgraduate students. Ok I'll ask them to clarify whether it's teaching-only or research-and-teaching position.

I would would guess that they are testing two things here: 1) Your abaility to simplify complex topics and present them in a way suitable for students, but 2) Judging not just if you can simplify it, but what the correct target level of complexity for second year undergrads.

I don't know what you mean by "postgraduate". Is it for masters's theses or doctoral dissertations or something less than either. Supervising doctoral dissertations requires deep knowledge of and probably research activity in the subfield. Otherwise the requirement is less in intensity, but perhaps more in breadth. This affects any answer.

I work at a research intensive UK university, and our teaching focused entrance positions are called "teaching fellows", not lecturers, though the pay scale is about the same. I thought most research universities in the UK use a variation on the theme to designate teaching only positions. Note that this might be different for post-1992 universities.

They didn't specify what "postgraduate" means, but I guess it mainly refers to masters students with the possibility to supervise phd students if I can get funding for that. I emailed them and they clarified it's a teaching & research post, so it's probably just badly advertised.

You’ve been shortlisted, so I recommend getting in touch and asking them directly what they are looking for in the talk. Personally, without further information, I’d interpret the request as asking you to present a talk about your own research (not just the broad field) but in a way that that would be interesting to a second-year student and assumes only the level of background knowledge that a second-year student in the UK would have. But your interpretation might also be correct, and it can’t hurt to ask.
It might also be worth clarifying the teaching vs research expectations. If it isn’t a standard teaching-and-research lectureship, I’d expect the ad to say so directly somewhere. Is it supervising undergraduate student research, or supervising research students (i.e., PhD students)?

Thank you for your advise. It's supervision of research projects of undergraduate and postgraduate students, although it's never said something like conduct research or securing research funding.
